# System Health »Process Manager

Tags: mysql, linux, whm

Can someone tell me what this command means

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld \
  --basedir=/usr \
  --datadir=/var/lib/mysql \
  --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin 
  - -user=mysql \
  --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/srv.myserver.com.err \
  --open-files-limit=10000 \
  --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/srv.myserver.com.pid
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question such that it is readable. Maybe you now could add what it is you want to know? Apart from a "tell me everything, since I have no idea"? You probably have a more specific question, since you ask in a programmers site? Basically it starts some executable that, by the name of it, most likely is or starts a MySQL database management system. Considering some options along the way.

Comment: I added an image to be more explicit. It is an error?

Comment: Since I do not know where that comes from, what it is meant to show (_you_ should know) I can only _guess_ here: this looks like a process list (only showing a single process, whyever). Why should that be an error? It is the database server process that takes 2.77% of the system memory and 16.37% of the CPU power. It is a process id ("pid") and can be traced or killed. _Why should that be an error?_ It is a command that was started and created a process that is running. Not more, not less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image attached was very helpful.

What you see there is not an error. It is simply the details mysql process would pull from the config file(generally stored at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) to load all the basic configs necessary to start mysql process.